# CSS navbar - menu options not staying inside the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have made a navbar with two menu options to the right. Both options will stay in the navbar when the browser window is wide enough but when resized, the second option always falls below the navbar. I have tried setting a minimum width to the navbar

```
#myNavbar{
    min-width:850px;
}
```

but that didn't help. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a sample of my the code I have: http://jsbin.com/nebilanefo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: `.navbar-nav > li {display:inline-block;}` fixed the issue I had on your fiddle.

Comment: @Jhecht this solved the problem thanks. Why didn't you put it as an answer?

Comment: It was pretty short, and it could have been that you had other styles in conflict with what I wrote so that it wouldn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

hi so you want the both options to stay in the purple bar and so its mobile freindly try using this code

```
#myNavbar{
  height: 80%;
  min-width: 100%;  
} 

#wrapper{
    min-width: 100%;    
}
```

see if this helps i tried it

or another css file might be overriding it so try this

```
#myNavbar{
min-width:850px !important;
```

}